# Webcam with good microphone for low-volume voice for Chromebook and Windows PC

Tags: pc, microphones, webcam, chromebook

I am looking for recommendations for a webcam with **good microphone for low-volume voice** for Chromebook and Windows PC.

- **Intended use**: Zoom meetings.
- **Audio**: **The person using it speaks in soft (low volume) voice, so the mic has to be able to transmit the sound well.**
- **Video**: Average quality is acceptable (audio is much more important).
- **Computer**: Chromebook (major use) and Dell Inspiron 5000 laptop running Windows 10 (minor use).
- **Budget**: $30-100.

Found so far these models, but also looking for better alternatives:

- [GESMA Webcam with Microphone, 1080P HD Streaming USB Computer Webcam [Plug and Play] [30fps] for PC Video Conferencing/Calling/Gaming, Laptop/Desktop Mac, Skype/YouTube/Zoom/Facetime](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087NN41JH)
- [Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008ZVRAQS)
- [NexiGo 2020 1080P 60FPS Webcam with Microphone, NexiGo N980P HD USB Web Camera, Built-in Dual Noise Reduction Mics, 120 Degrees Wide-Angle for Zoom YouTube Skype FaceTime Hangouts, PC Mac Laptop Desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DHPBP65)

Answer (score 0):

We ended up buying this webcam (not listed in the OP):

- [Aoozi Webcam 1080p, Webcam with Microphone, 1080p Streaming Web Camera, USB Webcam Widescreen for Video Calling Recording](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0897JCTRY)

We have been using it for 2 years, mostly with a Chromebook. It works fine with the **Skype web app** and the **Zoom app**.

The only con is that it is **not** recognized by the **Skype app** for ChromeOS.